# I've hidden a question and the answer below - Where are they?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I've hidden a question and the answer below.

> Know what to ask
>
> That is barely hidden
>
> Know the base numbers
>
> Answer very carefully
>
> Look to the words
>
> Life always finds a way
>
> The numbers are also important
>
> This universe is odd
>
> And even when you know
>
> Somehow everything is mysterious

Where are they?

Comment: As expected, the question and answer were quickly uncovered by Strawberry and Arth BUT there is another answer hidden here, loosely in the form of a Palindrome and I have an extra special, extra large, extra shiny +1 for whomever can tell me where it is :)   (Hint: Arth is bang on about the odd and even lines)

Comment: Never mind... Strawberry sussed it out.  Upvote Strawberry and Arth for being smartypantses.

Comment: Question: Where is the question? Answer: Below (this works if you see the question in the network questions tab: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NYmXM.png )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question, as found by @Strawberry, is:

> What is the answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything?

Because:

> There is one word of the question on each line, in order.. if the line has an even number of words choose the second, odd choose the first.

The answer is, of course:

> 42

As indicated by:

> There are 42 words in the quoted section of the question.

Comment: I think Arth's explanation warrants the win.

Comment: @BrentHackers, recounted using an online tool, still the same answer. Appreciate there may have been more to it, but if it looks like a duck and talks like a duck..

Comment: Not quite what I meant.  The answer is hidden more than once.    You have it of course and I'll mark your answer correct but there's a sneakier hiding place that you may get if you count again...

Comment: Well, the letters `F***Y T*O` are certainly contained with the text, but is that relevant?

Comment: @Strawberry not intentionally.  No.  Actually, if I'm being totally honnest.  It was a total fluke that the number of words ended up being 42 (spooky right?!) and that sort of ruined my slightly better hidden answer... :(  I should have specified that is was a Palindrome or something

Comment: We can use odds and evens to contrive a figure like '0101010', but it does seem a little too contrived.

Comment: @BrentHackers, 01011010 is 90 in decimal though.. Believe it or not, I actually already went down that route and discarded it. :(

Comment: um... :'( I'm having an off day?

Comment: @BrentHackers Not to worry, looks like the Universe provided an alternate path to the answer! Friends in high places, bizarre indeed. Fun puzzle though :)

Comment: I think the answer is 41 because "There are 42 words in the quoted section of the question." and `42 - 1 = 41`.

Answer (score 12):

> What is the answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything

Well, everyone knows that.

Comment: so the answer is 42?

Comment: But the universe is odd, and 42 is even. Ok wow, I just saw that.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  I'd have gone with

> very carefully

Because

> that answer appears to be hidden in plain sight.